# Why must the text be a unicode?

Tags: python

Why this code is not working?

```
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 24)
zahl = 99
img = font.render(("zahl  ",str(zahl)), True, WHITE)
screen.blit(img, (20, 20))enter code here
```

I get the message:
TypeError: text must be a unicode or bytes

Best regards
Joachim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`("zahl  ",str(zahl))` is a [tuple](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_tuples.asp). `render` expects either a string or a [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) instance. Try this:

```py
img = font.render("zahl  " + str(zahl), True, WHITE)
```